# How to get jspm/webpack/browserify/requirejs bundling working with msdeploy?

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, msdeploy, bundling-and-minification

I currently use jspm but the same issue applies with any other build-time bundling tool. I can't figure out how to get these to play well with msdeploy.

Here's the issue:

- I run jspm to produce one or more bundle files (one for each "chain" that I want).
- My application uses `System.import` (or `require` or just a script tag) to start these loading.

If I were to deploy everything to a directory and xcopy from there to the deployment server everything is copacetic. *However*, our devops team prefers to deploy using msdeploy. For this I'm supposed to point it at a csproj. If I do this then how does msdeploy know to deploy the generated bundles?

Comment: You can sync a folder with MSDeploy see http://sedodream.com/2012/08/20/WebDeployMSDeployHowToSyncAFolder.aspx

Comment: Saw this question and was going to post an answer, and then I realized - it's George!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an MSBuild project to accomplish this - one which hooks into the MSDeploy pipeline. I've provided a sample (one I'm currently using for a project) below; I'm likely going to release this as a Nuget package (along with some other MSBuild scripts that were written to take advantage of npm, jspm, and gulp).

The props file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
            FrontendDeploymentFiles;
            $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
        </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The targets file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="FrontendDeploymentFiles">
        <ItemGroup>
            <_CustomFiles Include="dist\**\*" />
            <_CustomFiles Include="jspm_packages\**\*" />

            <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
                <DestinationRelativePath>%(RelativeDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
            </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

This isn't exactly a drop-in for you as you're bundling your files, but the takeaway here is that you can define a glob pattern for your copy methods. Replace `jspm_packages` with whatever your bundles are (as the scripts I've provided are only for publishing to a development environment) and you should be good.

Hope this is helpful to anyone else who runs into this issue.